# XML comparison using XMLunit not working when elements are reordered

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xmlunit-2

I have two XMLs

```
<books><book language="English"><authors><author>Niklaus Wirth</author></authors></book><book language="English"><authors><author>Mark Twain</author></authors></book><book language="English"><authors><author>O.-J. Dahl</author></authors></book></books>


<books><book language="English"><authors><author>Niklaus Wirth</author></authors></book><book language="English"><authors><author>O.-J. Dahl</author></authors></book><book language="English"><authors><author>Mark Twain</author></authors></book></books>
```

The order of the last two `<author>` tags are different and they should be similar.
This is the code

```
public static void compare() throws FileNotFoundException{
        String sourceXML=convertXMLtoString(source);
        String targetXML=convertXMLtoString(target);
        System.out.println(sourceXML);
        System.out.println(targetXML);
        Diff mydiff=DiffBuilder.compare(sourceXML)
        .withTest(targetXML)
        .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
        .checkForSimilar()
        //.withNodeMatcher()
        .build();
        Iterable<Difference> differences = mydiff.getDifferences();
        for(Difference d:differences){
            System.out.println(d.toString());
        }
    }
```

This is the ouput.

```
Expected child 'author' but was 'null' - comparing <author...> at /books[1]/book[2]/authors[1]/author[1] to <NULL> (DIFFERENT)
Expected child 'null' but was 'author' - comparing <NULL> to <author...> at /books[1]/book[2]/authors[1]/author[1] (DIFFERENT)
Expected child 'author' but was 'null' - comparing <author...> at /books[1]/book[3]/authors[1]/author[1] to <NULL> (DIFFERENT)
Expected child 'null' but was 'author' - comparing <NULL> to <author...> at /books[1]/book[3]/authors[1]/author[1] (DIFFERENT)
```

Can anyone please tell me how to ignore this?I thought using NameandText with Element selector should ignore the order.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `byNameAndText` you make sure you pick the correct `author` tags, but this is far too late as XMLUnit needs to select the correct `book` for your comparison to succeed. Once it has settled on which `book` element to compare it is never going to search for elements in a different subtree.

I don't think `author` is what distinguishes the books in the end, but in absence of any other hints something like

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("book").thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./authors/author", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText)
    .build();
```

should probably work.